# How to calculate variable in Upstart script and use it?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, upstart

Is where any way to achieve this?

Some details:

I am trying to create log file for gunicorn with datetime in name.

Something like that, but it isn't works properly:

```
chdir /home/mypath
script
   log_file=./err_$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%T").log
   exec gunicorn --error-logfile $log_file
end script
```

This approach fails too:

```
exec gunicorn --error-logfile ./err_$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%T").log
```

Comment: Note that `exec` inside the `script` stanza is the shell command `exec`, not the Upstart `exec` stanza. It isn't necessary, and may be part of your problem.

Comment: @chepner without `exec` in `script` part it fails with `terminated with status 127`

Comment: An exit status of `127` typically means the shell could not find the named executable. This sounds like a path issue; what happens if you replace `gunicorn` with the full path (`/usr/bin/gunicorn`, or whatever is correct)?

Comment: @chepner it works fine by this way `exec gunicorn --error-logfile ./hard/coded/path/to.log`

Comment: I've tried `log_file=./err_$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%T").log > test.log 2>&1` it gives me `date: not found`..

Comment: Ah, it's `date` that can't be found, not `gunicorn`. (The `script` stanza runs a shell with the `-e` option set, so the first failed command--in this case, the one that sets `log_file`--causes the entire script to exit.) Try replacing `date` with a full path (usually `/bin/date`; it's odd that `date` would be missing.)

Comment: @chepner lol thats work now! Thanks a lot :)
You could write that as an answer. So I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the shell started by the `script` stanza is unable to find the `date` command in its path. Use a hardcoded path:

```
script
    log_file=./err_$(/bin/date +"%d_%m_%Y_%T").log
    gunicorn --error-logfile $log_file
end script
```